# Template Won't Load with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I am using Backbone.js for the first time and am following one of the many tutorials.

I can't get the second template to load once I press the button that is supposed to go to the template and am wondering if anyone can help solve the problem.

Here is my js code:

```
var Processes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/'
});

var ProcessView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.template',

    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($('#process-template').html())
        this.$el.html(template);

    }
});

var KLWView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.template',

    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($('#klw-template').html())
        this.$el.html(template);

    }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'process',
        'klw': 'klw'
    }
});

var processView = new ProcessView();
var klwView = new KLWView();

var router = new Router();

router.on('route:process', function(){
    console.log('home page loaded');
    processView.render();
});
router.on('route:klw', function(){
    console.log('klw page loaded');
    klwView.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

And here is the template view:

```
<script type="text/template" id="process-template">

    <div id="holder_process" class="container">
        <h1>KLW Process</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><button id="run" class="rndbuttoninpt">Run Now</button></li>
            <a href='#/klw'><li><button id="new" class="rndbuttoninpt">New KLW</button></li></a>
        </ul>
        <form id="process" class="container process_holder" method="post" action=''>

            <fieldset>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <label for="pname">Process Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pname" class="form-text">
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <label for="active" class="radio_label">Active:</label>
                    <div id="options">
                        <label for="yes" class="radio">Yes<input type="radio" name="active" id="yes"></label>
                        <label for="no" class="radio">No<input type="radio" name="active" id="no"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <label for="location">File Location:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="location" class="form-text">
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <label for="type">File Type:</label>
                    <select id="type" class="form-text">
                        <option>Type1</option>
                        <option>Type2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <label for="action">Action:</label>
                    <select id="action" class="form-text">
                        <option>Action1</option>
                        <option>Action2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <label for="action_name" class="action_name">Action Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="action_name" class="form-text">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="klw-template">
        <div id="holder" class="container">
           <h1>Code Here</h1>
        </div>

</script>
```

This is also the button that is supposed to get to the view:

```
<a href='#/klw'><li><button id="new" class="klwinpt">New KLW</button></li></a>
```

I'm aware that it could most likely be that I'm defining the view before the DOM is even loaded, if it is can someone point out how to solve that? This is the exact way the person in the tutorial is doing it and it is working just fine for them.

Comment: Where do you define the functions that the router should execute? (`process`and `klw`.

Comment: @KimGysen in the tutorial the person uses the router.on and underscore's render function for the router

Comment: Are you sure that `<a><li><button>` is valid HTML?

Comment: @muistooshort yes it was working when I just had
this.$el.html('Template loaded');

Comment: No, it isn't valid, an `<li>` cannot be the immediate child of an `<a>` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), expect some browsers to rewrite it and make a mess. Besides that, your question is incomplete. Are you getting error messages? Where is `#process-template`? Can you at least provide a functional demo?

Comment: @muistooshort I'm going to keep it for now because it's been working this whole time thanks for that info tho. The error I'm getting is TypeError: n is undefined

Comment: Let me guess, your template includes something like `<%= n %>`, right? And you might want to read the [`_.template` docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template) so that you know what it returns and the [jQuery `html` docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) so that you know with it does when you hand it a function.

Comment: @muistooshort no my template looks like what I showed in the question. You said my question is incomplete what is it that makes it incomplete? I've put all the code that I'm using and since I know nothing about backbone I'm following a tutorial. He is doing it this way exact and it's working fine for him. Sorry I don't have a live demo to show you

Comment: But what does `#process-template` look like? Which `this.$el.html` is triggering the error? If your tutorial is doing exactly what your code is doing then you need to find a better tutorial.

Comment: @muistooshort yes the tutorial is doing exactly what my code is doing. I edited it so you could see what the `#process-template` looks like. The `this.$el.html` that is triggering the error is the one inside the KLWView. Everything dealing with `#process-template` works just fine.

Comment: (1) Read the documentation links I give you. (2) Throw out that tutorial and find one that isn't garbage, that one is using invalid HTML and `.html` incorrectly.

Comment: Your problem cannot be due to the DOM not being present. `#process-template` renders fine, which proves your DOM has finished loading. I can't see anything in `#klw-template` that would make `_.template` complain. What would help would be the full Stack Trace of your error. Take a snapshot and post it here. If you're still concerned about the DOM loading, the simplest fix is to put your JavaScript at the end of your HTML document.

Comment: @Seebiscuit yes if you go here https://github.com/kaneisha/SSL/blob/master/Day7/images/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-23%20at%208.45.15%20AM.png you will see a screenshot of the complete error

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your code it seems you are doing something like this in render:

```
render: function () {
        var template = _.template($('#klw-template').html())
        this.$el.html(template);

    }
```

I think _.template("...") returns a function and you should be calling that function rather that directly passing it it html()

```
render: function () {
        var template = _.template($('#klw-template').html())
        this.$el.html(template());

    }
```

I think this should fix the issue

Comment: Yes, Underscore has changed its template function from a direct call to a function: http://underscorejs.org/#changelog.
Sadly, most Backbone tutorials havent updated to this new behaviour

Comment: Hi @2292amit thank you I made the change but sadly that does not work. I'm now working in Google's browser and I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. Could it be anything else? I know it's failing in the render function because it logs out klw page loaded in the console

Comment: Can you please share the call stack. I think that will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i suggest.

1. First, include the non-minified underscore library in your project, you don't want to debug your code on minified libraries.
2. Then, at the top of your `#klw-template` template include the following code `<%debugger %>`.
3. When you run your app in Chrome or Firefox with the debugger (Google DevTools or Firefox Firebug, for example), the runtime will break at the `<%debugger %>` line.

At this point you'll be *inside* the rendering of your Underscore.js template render and you'll be able to see what local variables are available to the template and what parameters the template renderer is looking for.